# Error using Android Design Support Library: attr backgroundTint not found

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Trying to use the new Design Support Library in my project, AAPT throws the following error:

```
Description: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'.
Resource:    /design/res/values/styles.xml
Location:    line 21
```

This is the affected entry in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_background</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="fabSize">normal</item>
    <item name="elevation">@dimen/fab_elevation</item>
    <item name="pressedTranslationZ">@dimen/fab_translation_z_pressed</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">?attr/colorControlHighlight</item>
    <item name="borderWidth">@dimen/fab_border_width</item>
</style>
```

I'm targeting my project to use SDK 21, with min SDK set to 17.

**Edit:** I have all SDK tools up to date.

Comment: Do you have this updated Android Support Library,
Android Support Repository,
Google Play Services,
Google Repository ???

Comment: @Elenasys Yes, I have all of them installed and updated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with @igece solution, but later I found out that the real issue is an outdated `appcompat-v7 library`.

After upgrading it to the **latest version** nothing had to be edited on Google's libraries.

Answer (score 32):

Add appcompat-v7 library as dependency to the design library project.

It resolved the same error for me.

Comment: Have you integrated design library in any of your eclipse projects. Do you need to check the 'Is Library" check box also. For me, this was unchecked when I imported the design support library.

Comment: Yes I have integrated the design library in my eclipse. For me also its unchecked. We need to change as library project by checking the check box.

Comment: @HarshalK, I already added appcompat-v7 reference and marked the imported project as a library. The problem is something else.

Comment: This should be up higher, solved my issue no problem - thanks.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be solved adding the `format` attribute to both `backgroundTint` and `backgroundTintMode` items in `/res/values/attrs.xml`:

**Before:**

```
<declare-styleable name="FloatingActionButton">
    <!-- Background for the FloatingActionButton -->
    <attr name="android:background"/>
    <attr name="backgroundTint"/>
    <attr name="backgroundTintMode"/>
```

**After:**

```
<declare-styleable name="FloatingActionButton">
    <!-- Background for the FloatingActionButton -->
    <attr name="android:background"/>
    <attr name="backgroundTint" format="color"/>
    <attr name="backgroundTintMode" format="integer"/>
```

Comment: Now the problem is that I'm unable to make any reference to design support library classes. Checked again and again the Java Build Paths configuration in my project to make sure there is a reference to the support library.

Answer (score 0):

Adding appcompat-v7 library in dependancy of design library project is the solution for this issue if you have already installed updated Android Support Repository and Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as comment under third answer, but code was not formatted properly. I have to add both dependencies below to resolve the issue:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```